# iPhone 7 not being recognized by computer

Tags: iphone, itunes, mac, backup, damage

I have an iPhone 7.  My screen broke so I got it replaced.  It went underwater and then the home button started vibrating when I pressed it.  The screen flickered in and out.  The next day I could press the home button and it would vibrate but the screen was completely off.  I plugged it into my computer and iTunes recognized it but I couldn't type in my passcode.

**How can I get a backup of my phone?**

Comment: It is recommended to contact Apple authorised service provider and get your iPhone 7 inspected by a technician.

Comment: Have you got iCloud backups on? Because that could be something.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a wired lightning keyboard, you can connect it to your iPhone, press the home button twice with 1 second delay to bring up the password screen, type in your password and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Your phone should unlock and you should be able to back it up. If you didn't sync it with the current computer before, your phone will ask you if you want to trust the current computer. You *might be able to* use the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key or the arrow keys to navigate between yes and no buttons and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to allow the computer to sync your iPhone **(not tested)**.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your LCD screen may be damaged as a result of the water contact. If possible try another replacement screen and that will confirm if its the motherboard or the visual ic chip.

P.s. After having a screen replaced your iPhone is no longer waterproof!